# Generate format-patch between two branches

Tags: git

I would like to know how to generate a format-patch between the
last commit of two branches.

I want to get exactly the same format as `format-patch` command.

I tried a command like `git diff b1..b2 -- > diff.patch` but it
does not give the output format I want to get.

Comment: Do you mean "git format-patch"? And if so, what is the problem with actually using that command?

Comment: `format-patch`, my bad. May be I did not understand very well format-patch. So, it would be like `git format-patch BRANCH1_LAST_COMMIT BRANCH2_LAST_COMMIT`?

Comment: What happens if you try `git format-patch branch1 branch2` ?

Comment: It creates a patch for each commit from the first commit of branch1 to the last commit of branch2

Comment: What format do you want?

Comment: I want a diff between the last commits of both branch1 and branch2. The format I want is the same as format-patch output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--stat` parameter to `git diff` is the format I was looking for, thanks @torek's comment.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get exactly the same format as format-patch command.

You can't get that, because `git format-patch` produces, as its output format, the result of formatting *one or more existing commits*.  Your diff between two branch tips is not an *existing commit*.

If what you want is not *exactly* the same format, but *approximately* the same format, you can get that.  How easy or difficult this is depends on how approximate you wish your generated patch to be.

Note that the output from `git format-patch` consists of two parts:

- a textual section representing the commit metadata; and
- a diff as produced by `git diff`.

These two parts then get a mailbox-style wrapping.  The `From` header uses the commit hash ID, which means there must be a single commit that produces the diff.  The Date: and Subject: headers encode some of the commit metadata, and the remainder goes in the text above the diff.

The first part is the one that is impossible to reproduce exactly, since *there is no commit involved* (hence no commit metadata).  The second part is the one that is easy to reproduce: just run `git diff` on the two commits in question.

> I tried a command like `git diff b1..b2 -- > diff.patch` but it does not give the output format I want to get.

In that case, you're going to have to be more explicit about what you're willing to accept.  What do you want in the first part?  Where will you get it, since there is no single commit from which to obtain it?

Comment: I want the little summary on changes after the email header of the output of format-patch. `git diff` does not give this summary.

Comment: Add `--stat` and/or `--summary` to your `git diff`.

Comment: `--stat` is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how to generate a format-patch between the last commit of two branches.
>
> I want to get exactly the same format as format-patch command.

Not sure if it is what you want, but to get the diff between two branches, say the development and a feature branch, named as `development` and `test`, in the format of format-patch, do

```
git format-patch -o ../ development..test
```